# why didBegin has no data about contact bodies?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection, game-physics

I am making a game that a player ( ball ) and enemy ( ball ) hit each other. sometimes `didBegin` func hold information about the two collided bodies and sometimes no, which lead to a crash and throwing an error of `exc_bad_instruction` , then I check the player and enemy with breakpoints and I find them `nil`. how that happen that sometimes it work and sometimes don't. please help.

**My Code :**

```
private var player: Player!

private func drawPlayer(color: SKColor, radius: CGFloat, cn: String) {
        player = Player.factory.createPlayer(color: color, radius: radius)
        player.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
        player.name = cn
        world.addChild(player)
    }

if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == bodyType.enemy.rawValue) && (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == bodyType.player.rawValue) {
        print(contact.bodyA.node?.name)
        print(contact.bodyB.node?.name)
        let player = contact.bodyB.node as? Player
        let hitter = contact.bodyA.node as? Enemy
}
```

I used the print to get the names sometimes it give me both names and sometimes it gives me both `nil` . the rest of code I didn't put it as it is not needed here.

**THE SOLUTION ::**

The problem as steve mentioned in his answer is that sometimes the `didBegin` method is being called on same collision objects twice . so it crash because at its first call I removed the objects so it finds `nil` second time. so as steve mentioned you should surround the logic with `if` and check if the two bodies are `nil` then this is the second call of `didBegin` and the objects have already been removed so you should not run the logic or it will run on nothing then crash. and if they are not `nil` you can run the code and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens if `bodyA` is the player and `bodyB` is the enemy? I suspect this situation is the cause of your "and sometimes no, which lead to a crash" problem.

In `didBegin()` do you remove any nodes from the scene (with `removeFromParent`)? That could cause the behaviour as SK sometimes generates multiple calls to `didBegin` for a single collision. If you remove either or both of the nodes involved in the collision the first time that `didBegin` is called, then the second time it's called (this is within the same game loop) some of your nodes and/or their attributes could be `nil`.

Bear in mind that the objects passed to `didBegin` in the `SKMPhysicsContact` object are physics bodies and not the nodes themselves. It's possible for the physics bodies to still exist even though you've removed the nodes themselves (in a previous didBegin). This means that unless you access the actual nodes in didBegin, you might not get a crash and if you are doing some simple checks e.g. if the player has hit a coin or an enemy, then you might increase a score twice, or remove two lots of health etc.

There are many ways to handle this - including, but not limited to:

- Check if a body is nil before doing anything with it. (If it is nil, then assume you've already processed it's collision and removed it).
- Add the node to be removed to a set, and then removing all the nodes
  in the set in `didFinishUpdate`, after all the calls to `didBegin`
  have been made. You might need to set a flag in the nodes `userData` property to stop it being processed twice.

Plus some other techniques. Search for sprite-kit multiple collisions.

To deal with the 'which is bodyA and which is bodyB' problem, I like to code didBegin: like this:

```
    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

        switch contactMask {

        case categoryBitMask.player | categoryBitMask.enemy:
           print("Collision between player and enemy")
           let enemy = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == categoryBitMask.thisMine ? contact.bodyA.node! : contact.bodyB.node!
           enemy.explode()

        default :
           //Some other contact has occurred
           print("Some other contact")
    }  
}
```

This is really only safe if your nodes only belong to one category at a time, which is up to you to determine.

Comment: yes i use remove parent for both enemy and player and then i draw the player again in the same place so the game continue , but it works with it for the first 3 or 2 times then crash on the later

Comment: I suspect you need to indicate that this collision has already been processed. You could set a flag in userData and then clear the flag in update(), as you'll be on a new game loop by then and and collisions between player and enemy will be new ones.

Comment: you mean i add the variable `collided = true` after they begin colliding ?

Comment: @AhmedNader - that might work, and then set it to false in update(). then at the start of your didBegin simply return if it's true.

Comment: ok you are right but i made the first option you gave me and worked , i surrounded the whole logic with checking if the both nodes are nil or no , if they are nil i dont run the logic but the wiered is that the enemy is removed although i didnt enter that logic part !

Comment: @AhmedNader. Glad it's working. The first time didBegin is called, the bodies would not have been nil and your removal code would have run. Then when didbegin is called again for the same collision, the bodies are nil and the code is not run. If you put some print statements in such as "player has hit enemy" and "Nil check preventing double collision" you'll probably see more 'collsion' messages than 'nil' messages. .

Comment: ok you are right i checked it , it gives me the two names , and sometimes it gives me the two names and two nils which means sometimes it call `didBeign` once and sometimes till call `didBegind` twice

Comment: @AhmedNader - yes - didBegin is not always called multiple times for the same collision. It depends on exactly how the 2 physics bodies involve contact each other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134458/discussion-between-steve-ives-and-ahmed-nader).